# ExtractValue function of mysql not working

Tags: mysql, extract-value

```
select extractvalue( SELECT CONCAT("'",(SELECT LCASE('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<resp>
<dlrdtls>
<MessageId>43745973-737b-4c71-926f-797c0c9407a6</messageid>
<deliverystatus>failed</deliverystatus>
</dlrdtls>
</resp>')),"'"),'/resp/dlrdtls/messageid')  
as id ;
```

I want to extract value for tag MessageId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the inner `SELECT` statments like

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(CONCAT("'",(LCASE('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<resp>
<dlrdtls>
<MessageId>43745973-737b-4c71-926f-797c0c9407a6</messageid>
<deliverystatus>failed</deliverystatus>
</dlrdtls>
</resp>')),"'"),'/resp/dlrdtls/messageid')  
AS id ;
```

the query works this way but in reality the `CONCAT` function is also not needed